ffmpeg convert container format without re-encoding
This works:
ffmpeg -i test.caf   recoded.opus

ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, caf, from 'test.caf':
  Duration: 00:00:05.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: opus (opus / 0x7375706F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (opus (native) -> opus (libopus))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libopus @ 0x7fa8a0708580] No bit rate set. Defaulting to 96000 bps.
Output #0, opus, to 'recoded.opus':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.3.100
  Stream #0:0: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc60.3.100 libopus
size=      69kB time=00:00:05.33 bitrate= 106.2kbits/s speed= 112x
video:0kB audio:68kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.118284%

This does not work
ffmpeg -i test.caf  -acodec copy  recoded.opus
ffmpeg version 6.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.0.40.1)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/6.0_2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags='-Wl,-ld_classic' --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libspeex --enable-libsoxr --enable-libzmq --enable-libzimg --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-videotoolbox --enable-audiotoolbox
  libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
  libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
  libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
  libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
  libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
  libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
  libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, caf, from 'test.caf':
  Duration: 00:00:05.34, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 32 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Audio: opus (opus / 0x7375706F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
[opus @ 0x7f875cf076c0] No extradata present
[out#0/opus @ 0x7f875cf07600] Could not write header (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input
[aost#0:0/copy @ 0x7f875cf08240] Error initializing output stream:
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times

Clearly ffmpeg is able to read and decode the frames from the .caf container correctly, because it has no issues re-encoding them to .ogg container. But direct frame copy fails?

Could you please express a specific question you want solved?

From what I have read, opus extradata is necessary for FFmpeg to save the stream to a file, however, this is FFmpeg policy to not create missing opus extradata by the decoders : it is only created by the encoders.
That is why the first command works (re-encoding), while the second fails (remuxing).
In other words, this is normal, expected behavior from FFmpeg.
You can't stream copy an opus stream if it misses extradata, unless FFmpeg developers change their policy about that.
Useful references :

https://lists.ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-devel/2020-December/274056.html
https://avidemux.org/smif/index.php?topic=18481.0

